# If I would like to massively rewrite a question, should I just open a new one instead?

Tags: support, editing, questions

I have a question that I later discovered was too much general and should've been much more accurate, but a rewrite of it would mean practically to change the question (although it would be on exactly the same subject). Should I do it, or should I simply open a new one?

I will add that, one of my main concerns is that if I would simply rewrite it, it might go unnoticed and people that have already participated in the question won't come back to reply to the better explained question.

Comment: Is it [Does science forces us to embrace materialism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48607/does-science-forces-us-to-embrace-materialism/48611#48611)

Comment: @Conifold yep, I have yet gotten to make that edit, to be honest mainly because of the chat with you, it solved many of my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not go unnoticed, because edits bump a post to the front page and if the original question was closed, editing will send it to the review queue for reopening.

However, be aware:

- If the original question had answers already, be sure that the answers are still relevant after the edit. Otherwise that may be annoying for the people who have put effort into writing an answer.
- If the original question has a lot of downvotes, it may be better to ask a new question (referring to the old one), because people may not bother to read a question if they see it has a low score.

Comment: Thanks! It does have an answer that *might* not fit the edit, but it's still relevant (although I did decline the answer in a comment to it, so it isn't very relevant either way).